# When are pin assignments on electronic modules "user-level questions"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question appears to be gathering close votes for the reason "This is a user-level question, not about electrical engineering."

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115681/can-the-spi-pins-of-an-arduino-be-separated-from-spi

Are we banning discussion of electronic modules used in electronic designs?

If so, let's go through the list and make sure to close questions discussing bluetooth, ethernet, wifi, and microcontroller modules. Also we should ask anyone presenting a question to the site whether they are using a module or not, so we can make sure we aren't supporting people who aren't "real" electrical engineers.

I don't understand the rational behind this decision, but if we're going down this route let's at least be consistent.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Refering to Arduino enthusiasts as ["insignificant, disliked"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/weenie) isn't appropriate for a site where all users are expected to [be nice](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Please consider deleting your comment, and adding a respectful answer sharing your reasons for disagreeing with the post.

Comment: I see my comment about arduino users got deleted, but that doesn't change the fact that they need to learn they don't belong here, with their "shields" and "sketches" and general non-interest in actually understanding the underlying electronics. A good test is if it doesn't matter that they are asking about a arduino or a bare microcontroller, then it's OK. If it appears to be arduino-specific, then the internet equivalent of tarring and feathering (downvoting to oblivion and finding any excuse to close the question) is necessary else we'll be overrun by the unwashed masses.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Your opinion is in the minority, and unnecessarily anti-social. You seem to apply the filter of "If **I** don't do it, it's not EE" or "If **I** can't understand it, then it doesn't belong". It's fine that you don't want to answer or interact with Arduino users, that's your choice... but you go out of your way to be seen as rude as possible, ***and that is not acceptable***. If you cannot keep criticisms technical in nature, they will be deleted. If you close just because it is Arduino, it will be reopened.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Consider adding "arduino" to your ignored tags: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/4512/ so you don't have to be unnecessarily exposed to the "unwashed masses".

Comment: The only trouble with a lot of Arduino users with no electrical/electronic back ground is they have never wanted or needed to go deeper. Here is a learning opportunity for them to go deeper... it's an ideal way to guide them deeper.

Comment: We don't need to be elitist. You don't have to be a general contractor or carpenter or plumber to ask a question on DIY.se. If you have a problem that the community can help you solve, it doesn't matter if your only trying to get something done and have no interest in the underlying expertise. If you are interested, great, we support that too. But the only reason we should reject something is if the question itself doesn't belong. We shouldn't judging wether the asker is worthy, or interested in anything further when closing a question. Does it fit the site guidelines?

Answer (score 8):

This sort of closing is a bit overzealous, in my opinion.

This sort of Arduino question is on-topic *here*.